# wordpress pagination showing when there is only one post

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have several posts that i don't want to show on the blog section so I have set up a query like so:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
'posts_per_page' => 10, 
'category__not_in'=>array(5,3,17), 
'paged'=>$paged ) );
```

So now only the posts that I want display.

As it happens there is only one of them...

However, at the moment at the page bottom it is showing pagination links to older posts - which I guess is because its still including the posts from the unwanted categories. When I press the 'older posts' button, it goes to a page asking me to do my first post.

So the pagination is nearly working, but not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine. you can use the plugin [WP-Paginate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/)

for the smooth working of the project